# PHP, need to subtract 12 hours and 30 minutes from a DateTime

Tags: php, datetime, date

I have a PHP `DateTime` variable.

How can I reduce or subtract 12hours and 30 minutes from this date in at PHP runtime?

Comment: if its mysql, i would use DATE_SUB()

Comment: Have you consider select an answer?

Answer (score 35):

Subtract 12 Hours and 30 minutes from a DateTime in PHP:

```
$date = new DateTime();
$tosub = new DateInterval('PT12H30M');
$date->sub($tosub);
```

The P stands for Period.  The T stands for Timespan.

See [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [DateTime::sub](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php), and [DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) in the PHP manual. You'll have to set the `DateTime` to the appropriate date and time, of course.

Answer (score 5):

Try with:

```
$date = new DateTime('Sat, 30 Apr 2011 05:00:00 -0400');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT12H30M'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

//Result

```
2011-04-30 05:00:00
2011-04-29 16:30:00
```

Answer (score 3):

Try `strtotime()` function:

```
$source_timestamp=strtotime("Sat, 30 Apr 2011 05:00:00 -0400");
$new_timestamp=strtotime("-12 hour 30 minute", $source_timestamp);
print date('r', $new_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it will be useful for some cases

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->modify('-12 hours -30 minutes');

echo $date->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

try using this instead

```html
//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('GMT');

//set an date and time to work with
$start = '2014-06-01 14:00:00';

//display the converted time
echo date('Y-m-d H:i',strtotime('+1 hour +20 minutes',strtotime($start)));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not so familiar with the spec of DateInterval like PT12H30M you can proceed with more human readable way using DateInterval::createFromDateString as follows :

```
$date = new DateTime();
$interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('12 hour 30 minute');
$date->sub($interval);
```

Or with direct interval in sub function like below :

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->sub(DateInterval::createFromDateString('12 hour 30 minute'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Store it in a `DateTime` object and then use the `DateTime::sub` method to subtract the timespan.

Answer (score 0):

I used in one line, for 12 hours only, and just as an hour display

```
$date = new DateTime(); $date->modify('-12 hours'); echo $date->format('H')-0;
```

I used the -0 since sometimes it put a 0 in front of the digit unless I done that, strange.

Answer (score -1):

[Here is detailed description of date function,](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php)

Comment: That's not very helpful in this case. He really should be using a `DateTime` object.

Comment: yeah updated it .. actually i saw multiple questions from him here and there on datetime object so it will be handy for him.

Answer (score -1):

Using simply `strtotime`

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("-12 hour -30 minutes"));
```

Using `DateTime` class

```
$date = new DateTime("-12 hour -30 minutes");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```